# How can I see all edits that others have made to my posts?

Tags: feature-request

I just stumbled upon one of my answers that clearly wasn’t written by me. Someone else had added lots of things to make my answer worse. I reverted that, and I’m fine with that.

Now I wonder which of my other answers have been edited as well. So I’d like to see a list of all my posts where the last edit is not from me, so I can recheck what others have done to my posts and whether I want to revert or improve them as well.

How can I get this list of edits?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a list of all edits to your posts, you can go to your profile, to the "responses" tab, and select "revisions" there.

For all posts where the latest edit is not yours, you should probably use the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com). See this query: 
[All posts of a user where the last edit is not made by themselves](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/257867/all-posts-of-a-user-where-the-last-edit-is-not-made-by-themselves)

```sql
SELECT Id AS [Post Link], LastEditorUserId AS [User Link]
FROM Posts WHERE OwnerUserId = ##UserId##
AND LastEditorUserId != ##UserId##
```

Note that SEDE data is cached and updated once a week.

Comment: This is so obvious that I should have found it myself by carefully looking at my profile. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can find all the revisions that people made to your posts at this link

https://stackoverflow.com/users/225757/roland-illig?tab=responses&sort=revisions

Or just go to your profile, click responses, click revisions.

This will include revisions that aren't the last one, but if there's not a lot, it shouldn't be too hard to go through them.